# 3 holders inside listview and Performance

Tags: android, performance, listview

I Have a 3 holders. 1 holder for 1 item. 
Method getView looks:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
    int type = checkDialogType(mCursor);
    Holder holder = null;
    if (convertView != null){
        holder = (Holder)convertView.getTag(type);
        if (holder == null){
            holder = createHolderByType(type, parent);
        }
    } else {
        holder = createHolderByType(type, parent);
    }
    return holder.fillView(mCursor, position);         //convertView
}
```

Where content of createHolderByType():

```
public Holder createHolderByType(int type, ViewGroup parent){
    View v;
    if (type == IN_TYPE){
        v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_incoming_item, parent, false);
        return new InHolder(v, mCursor, mContext, this, IN_TYPE);
    } else if (type == OUT_TYPE){
        v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogs_outcoming_item, parent,false);
        return new OutHolder(v, mCursor, mContext, this, OUT_TYPE);
    } else {
        v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogs_chat_item, parent, false);
        return new ChatHolder(v, mCursor, mContext, this, CHAT_TYPE);
    }
}
```

It works fine, But for 39 items in listView method createHolderByType was called 19 times. For create a holder I need inflate xml. It's very expensive. If i trying use same view for holder or saving holder in memory - it doesn't work. Can i increase performance with some tricks?

**UPD:**
There is one holder:

```
public class InHolder extends Holder {
private View baseView;
private TextView fio;
private TextView message;
private TextView date;
private ImageView isOnline;
private int type;
private ImageView senderIMG;

public InHolder(View v, Cursor dialogCursor, Context context, DialogCurAdapter adapter, int type){
    super(dialogCursor, context, adapter);
    fio = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.fio);
    senderIMG = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.sender_image);
    message = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_preview);
    date = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.date);
    isOnline = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.isonline);
    this.type= type;
    baseView = v;
    baseView.setTag(type, this);
}

@Override
public View fillView(Cursor dialogCursor, final int position) {
    try{
        int ownerID = dialogCursor.getInt(ownerIndex);
        User usr = mDButils.getUserByID(ownerID);
        String messageText = Html.fromHtml(dialogCursor.getString(bodyIndex)).toString();
        date.setText(DateUtils.getTime(dialogCursor.getInt(dateIndex), mContext));
        message.setText(messageText);

        if (messageText == null || messageText.equals("")){
            if (dialogCursor.getInt(hasAttIndex) == 1){
                message.setText(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.attachment));
                message.setTextColor(getColor(R.color.date_blue_to_white_selector));
            }

        }

        if (dialogCursor.getInt(hasAttIndex)  == 1){
            String[] attaches = dialogCursor.getString(attTypeIndex).split(",");
        }

        if (dialogCursor.getInt(readstateIndex) == 0){
            baseView.setBackgroundDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.lightblue_to_transparent_selector));
        } else baseView.setBackgroundDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.white_to_blue_selector));

        if (usr != null){
            mImageLoader.displayImage(usr.getImageURL(), senderIMG);
            fio.setText(usr.getFirstName() + " " + usr.getLastName());
            isOnline.setVisibility(usr.isOnLine()  == 1  ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            AsyncUserLoader userLoader = new AsyncUserLoader(mContext) {
                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(User user) {
                    if (user != null){
                        mDialogAdapter.updateItem(position);
                    }
                }
            };
            userLoader.execute(Integer.parseInt(ownerID + ""));
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return baseView;
}

@Override
public int getType() {
    return type;
}
}
```

Comment: do you actually add the holder as tag to your view ?

Comment: Yes i do. it is inside constructor of holder

Comment: and fillView returns that particular view ?

Comment: yes, i posted one holder.See upd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I made a complex container when all views which i need. And depend of type of view i make they visible or invisible. So i don't need inflate xml when convertView doesn't match with type.

Answer (score 0):

You could have multiple layouts implementation for BaseAdapter as given in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777272/android-listview-with-different-layout-for-each-row) and this [article](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296)

**Note**: in getItemViewType(int position) you can use checkDialogType(mCursor); to find what layout type to use. But getItemViewType(int position) should return value between 0 - 2 (when count is 3).

Comment: In examples which you gave we can see following: mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item1, null); He inflate item if type doesn't match. I do same. I will try use base adapter